# The submit buttons need a focus indication

Tags: feature-request, design

Most Stack Exchange sites make it possible to see when a button got focus. When using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key for submitting a question or answer this is quite useful to make sure you don't accidentally open a link by hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and lose your text input.

For example on the [Bitcoin SE](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com), this is how the submit button looks:

> [image: submit button without focus]

And this is how it looks when focused (by alt-tabbing twice from the text input field):

> [image: submit button with focus].

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Perhaps it will get a bit more attention this way.

Comment: Done. It also counts for the Add Comment button :)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been done with the redesign a couple of years ago. The text of the button switches from dark to white when the button gets focus.